# How can I show watermark in data table filter?

Tags: jsf, filter, primefaces

I have a `<p:column>` with a filter.
I would like to show it with a watermark.
This is what I have tried:

```
<p:column id="carType" filterBy="#{car.carType}" >
    <h:outputText value="#{car.carType}" />
    <p:watermark forElement="carType"
                 value="Car Type"/>
</p:column>
```

However, that didn't show up. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
     <h:form id="parametersListForm">      

    <p:dataTable id="parameteresList" value="#{parameterController.lstParameter}"
                 var="parameters" styleClass="tnt-main-table"> 

    <p:column id="columnRefType" filterBy="#{parameters.beRefType}" >
        <h:outputText value="#{parameters.beRefType}" />
        <p:watermark forElement="parametersListForm:parameteresList:columnRefType:filter"
                     value="#{msgs['parameters.beRefType.label']}"/>  
        </p:column>
     </p:dataTable>              
</h:form>
```

[Also see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522576/how-to-show-water-mark-in-filter-in-primefaces)

Comment: I have to give total path for 'forElement' ryt?

Comment: Yes. Like this formId:tableId:columnId:filter

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem, and after reading about `p:watermark` I've decided I don't prefer to give the full path to the filter. I've added the following snippet under the `p:dataTable` definition instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input.ui-column-filter').attr('placeholder','#{msgs['filter_placeholder']}"');
</script>
```

Of course, it will enrich ALL column filters in ALL tables, but you can always append data table id to the query...